# Add a basemap for ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online-basemaps

How do you add a basemap for ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?

For example the Esri [World Topographic Map](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7dc6cea0b1764a1f9af2e679f642f0f5)

With this URL: https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]

m.addBasemap("https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer")
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last) In  [6]: Line 5:
> m.addBasemap("https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer")
>
> File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy_mp.py, in
> addBasemap: Line 2374:  return
> convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addBasemap(*gp_fixargs((basemap_name,),
> True)))
>
> ### RuntimeError: Cannot find Basemap :
> https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass a name, not a URL.  From the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm#M2_GUID-CD5119D8-1DD8-46A3-9051-3DFE58C6B5A6):

```
addBasemap (basemap_name)
```

| **Parameter** | **Explanation** | **Data Type** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| basemap_name | The name of the basemap *as it appears in the basemap gallery*. | String |

If you want to add a custom basemap, use `addDataFromPath`.

Comment: Thanks. So, this works `m.addDataFromPath("https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer")`

Comment: By the way, the basemap from the url looks a bit different (when loaded) to the default ones of `["World Topographic Map", "World Hillshade"]`. Do you know how I would add those using ArcPy?

Comment: I've worked out how to not remove them in the first place by using the `dataType` in `arcpy.Describe()`.